# ViewBag RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ProfileId'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having trouble passing a list through `ViewBag.StaffList` to the view to display to the user. On this particular page, I only need to display 4 out of the 11 columns. I've tried referencing other similar questions from stack overflow and other sites before posting. Every time I make a change that appears would work, a different error would appear. I am using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core. I am really stuck on this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my Controller:

```
var StaffList = db.StaffProfiles.Where(a => a.Artist).Select(b => new { b.ProfileId, b.FirstName, b.Title, b.ProfilePictureId }).ToList();
ViewBag.StaffList = StaffList;
return View();
```

Here is my View:

```
@foreach (var employee in ViewBag.StaffList)
{
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb30">
        <div class="team-card-default">
            <img src="~/media/images/team/artists/@employee.ProfileId/@employee.ProfilePictureId" alt="@employee.FirstName" class="img-fluid" width="500" height="500">
            <div class="text-center"><h4 class="mb0 text-uppercase">@employee.FirstName</h4></div>
            <div class="text-center"><span>@employee.Title</span></div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a asp-controller="team" asp-action="profile" asp-route-id="@employee.ProfileId" class="btn btn-lg btn-rounded btn-primary">View My Profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class StaffProfilesModel
{
    public string ProfileId { get; set; }
    public bool EmployeeActive { get; set; }
    public bool Artist { get; set; }
    public bool Operations { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePictureId { get; set; }
    public string SampleOneId { get; set; }
    public string SampleTwoId { get; set; }
    public string SampleThreeId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you didn't assign the model type when querying the resource, try to modify the LINQ Query code as below:

```
        var StaffList = db.StaffProfiles.Where(a => a.Artist)
            .Select(b => new StaffProfilesModel() { 
                ProfileId = b.ProfileId, 
                FirstName= b.FirstName, 
                Title= b.Title, 
                ProfilePictureId = b.ProfilePictureId })
            .ToList();
        ViewBag.StaffList = StaffList;
```

You could also create a new page model to display the selected properties.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think use of viewmodel required here. you can directly pass the model through view.

```
return View(stafflist);
```

And after this, you can try scaffloding for view.

in view:

```
@model List<StaffList>
```

now

```
 @forech ( var employee in model){
```

//remaining code
}